# How to read a BMP packet from Huawei Watch GT-DEE by gatttool?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4, gatttool

Currently I am doing a project which is requiring some sensor reading from `Huawei Watch GT-DEE` with `gatttool`, `Python` and `Raspberry Pi 4`. Here, the server and the client are Huawei Watch and Raspberry Pi respectively. However, I got [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/using-python-to-store-data-from-many-ble-devices) which pretty much close to my target. I was looking for more detail and got [this article](http://blog.firszt.eu/index.php?post/2015/09/13/bt) and [this article](https://www.instructables.com/Reading-Values-From-a-BLE-Device-Using-CSR1010-and/). Anyway, I am getting following BLE `primary` services:

```
[aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0009 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x000a, end grp handle: 0x000d uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0010, end grp handle: 0x0020 uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x002a, end grp handle: 0x0034 uuid: 0000fe86-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0100, end grp handle: 0x0112 uuid: 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0300, end grp handle: 0xffff uuid: 00003802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

and getting following characteristics:

```
[aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff][LE]> characteristics
handle: 0x0002, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0003, uuid: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0004, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0005, uuid: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0006, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0007, uuid: 00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0008, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0009, uuid: 00002ac9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000b, char properties: 0x20, char value handle: 0x000c, uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0011, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0012, uuid: 00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0013, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0014, uuid: 00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0015, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0016, uuid: 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0017, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0018, uuid: 00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0019, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x001a, uuid: 00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001b, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x001c, uuid: 00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001d, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x001e, uuid: 00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001f, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0020, uuid: 00002a2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002b, char properties: 0x0c, char value handle: 0x002c, uuid: 0000fe01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002d, char properties: 0x10, char value handle: 0x002e, uuid: 0000fe02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0030, char properties: 0x0c, char value handle: 0x0031, uuid: 0000fe03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0032, char properties: 0x10, char value handle: 0x0033, uuid: 0000fe04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0101, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0102, uuid: 00002a4a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0103, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0104, uuid: 00002a4b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0106, char properties: 0x04, char value handle: 0x0107, uuid: 00002a4c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0108, char properties: 0x12, char value handle: 0x0109, uuid: 00002a22-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x010b, char properties: 0x0e, char value handle: 0x010c, uuid: 00002a32-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x010d, char properties: 0x12, char value handle: 0x010e, uuid: 00002a4d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0111, char properties: 0x06, char value handle: 0x0112, uuid: 00002a4e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0301, char properties: 0x1e, char value handle: 0x0302, uuid: 00004a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

According to [this article](https://www.instructables.com/Reading-Values-From-a-BLE-Device-Using-CSR1010-and/), 2a00 service (uuid: 0000**2a00**-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, char value handle by 0x0003) refers to the device name (1800 in primary) which I am getting correctly as follows:

```
[aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff][LE]> char-read-hnd 0x0003
Characteristic value/descriptor: 48 55 41 57 45 49 20 57 41 54 43 48 20 47 54 2d 44 45 45
```

However, I was looking for BMP value which is defined by `2a37` service which is missing in the `characteristics` (or `180d` in primary) output section. According the [specifications](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/wearables/watch-gt/specs/) (please have a look at Sensors section), it has `Optical heart rate sensor`. Anyway, I can see the heart rate at the **watch screen** as well as in the **Health app** in the mobile phone.

**Question:**

Why `gatttool` is not showing the service `2a37` in characteristics or `180d` in primary section?

Comment: Maybe the watch just does not use the official characteristic for the BMP value. You could try using the nRF Connect app on your phone to find out which characteristic actually contains the wanted value, but there is no way of telling whether that would be successful. You would need to use a BLE sniffer to find out which data is actually read by your phones Health app. The protocolll could be something Huawei specific